# PHP работа с файлом

Tags: php

Есть обычный текстовый документ t.txt. В нем записаны 3 числа. Как с помощью PHP достать из файла числа.И выполнить цикл.

```
while ($i <= value3) {
$result ='';
if ($i%$value1==0) {
    $result .='F';} 
if ($i%$$value2==0) {
    $result .='B';}
if (!$result) {
    $result = $i;} 
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: пример записи в t.txt: 2 5 20

Comment: Всего 3 числа ? или на каждой строке по 3 числа ?

Comment: В файле всего три числа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Методов много, можно просто использовать функцию `file()`, примерный код:

```
$datas = file('/path/to/text.txt');

// Осуществим проход массива и выведем содержимое 
foreach ($datas as $key => $data) {
    echo $data;
}
```